# Scala generic arrays instantiating

Tags: arrays, scala, generics, type-mismatch

I have a function that makes Arrays of specific type:

```
def mkArray[A:ClassTag:Ordering](size:Int):Array[A] = Array.ofDim[A](size)
```

And I want to make array arr of type Int or String depending on String str like so:

```
var arr = if(str=="i"){mkArray[Int](size)}else{mkArray[String](size)}
```

and now I try to add values to the array like so:

```
arr(n) = num.toInt // num is String like "123"
```

But it says:

```
- type mismatch; found : Int required: _366 where type _366 >: Int 
 with String
```

How can I get around this, making arr of type Array[Int] or Array[String] depending on string str?

Any help is appreciated,
Thanks!

Comment: Instead of using `str` with values `"i"` etc, you use `mkArray[Int]` directly. Try be more explicit to the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Scala is a statically typed language, and in your case the type of `arr` is `Array[_ >: Int with String]`. Hence, if you give it an Int, you get a type error.

Depending on how you're using the array further in your code, I'd recommend you take a look at Either[1], since it may be helpful in keeping an Array[Either], and processing it using pattern matching differently for when it contains an Int vs String.

[1] http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2013/01/02/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-7-the-either-type.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The Array is meant to be used as input for sorting algorithm, and speed is of great importance(its a school project) so I would think comparing directly Int or String would be a lot faster than using this Either type. I had implemented my own value wrapper class that could contain either string or int but that wasnt fast enough for this assignment. So is there any way around this so that I could compare directly Ints or Strings?

Comment: Its hard to optimize without knowing exact code, but you may be better off keeping two arrays, one for integers, one for strings.